# how to permission uploaded file correctly

Tags: php, unix, file-upload

I have an upload script that uploads a zip file to a directory on my website, it then unzips the file and creates a directory for each file uploaded.

```
drwxrwxrwx   7 Fabulous  admin    238 12 Jan 18:20 .
drwxrwxrwx  39 Fabulous  admin   1326 12 Jan 12:28 ..
-rwxr--r--@  1 Fabulous  admin  15364 12 Jan 18:21 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x   4 nobody    admin    136 12 Jan 18:20 2012_06
drwxr-xr-x   4 nobody    admin    136 12 Jan 18:20 2012_07
-rwxr--r--   1 Fabulous  admin   2904 31 Oct 16:11 index.php
```

I have another php script that runs which copies the files in the directories `2012_06` and `2012_07` which where created by the upload script. Every thing is working fine via the browser. However I am trying to automate the process via the command line using the unix command line to call the scripts.

**The problem** is the script runs if I change ownership of the directories to Fabulous by using the following commands

```
cd upload

sudo chown -R Fabulous:admin .
```

However when I do this then my upload script `index.php` no longer has permission access to upload files to the upload directory unless I change ownership back to nobody.

**Error Message**

> Warning:
>   rename(/htdocs/data_vis/upload/2012_06/Audit_Log.csv,htdocs/data_vis/data_out/2012_06_Audit_Log.csv): Permission denied in
>   /htdocs/data_vis/rename_files_in_sdir_with_sdir_name_prefix.php on line 27

Any suggestions/advice or fixes on what I should be doing or the correct way to resolve this via permissioning or any other method are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either add them both to a group or have the file owned by nobody and group owned by Fabulous you dont need it to be admin, root can access everything anyway

the easiest way is make sure the group stays the same is using sticky bits

if /path/to/dir is owned by the correct group

`chmod g+s /path/to/dir`

will make it so all new folders under `/path/to/dir` eg `/path/to/dir/1` are owned by the same group as `/path/to/dir` instead of the users default group

https://superuser.com/questions/102253/how-to-make-files-created-in-a-directory-owned-by-directory-group

Then  both your web application should be ok and your cron script without modifing the code

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: What access do you have to the server ?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to change ownership of the files in the directory so the other scripts can use the files.

```
<?php

// File name and username to use
$file_name= "foo.php";
$path = "/home/sites/php.net/public_html/sandbox/" . $file_name ;
$user_name = "fred";

// Set the user
chown($path, $user_name);

// Check the result
$stat = stat($path);
print_r(posix_getpwuid($stat['uid']));

?>
```